# pgrep process count show extra count

Tags: bash, sh

I've a scirpt name server.sh

```
  #!/bin/bash
 
  process_count=$(ps aux | grep server.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l )
  echo "total process running:"
  echo $process_count

... other script code
```

when I run script I get output as

```
./server.sh
total process running:
2
```

Why do I get process count as 2 instead of 1? I only have one script running and have also excluded grep process.
Even using pgrep -f server.sh and excluding pgrep gives 2 as process count.

Comment: There are 2 instead of 1 because `ps` also counts the `grep server.sh` command.

Comment: Somehow the `grep -v grep` does not subtract that grep line.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: To investigate your problem, remove the `wc` command and examine the output

Comment: I see two instances of script running and I think I found why this is happening
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666529/pgrep-process-count-show-extra-count  please go through the comments

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to redirect the output of `ps` into a temp file, then grep that file. That will eliminate extra processes.

```sh
ps aux > /tmp/ps.txt
process_count=$(grep server.sh /tmp/ps.txt | wc -l)
rm /tmp/ps.txt
```

Comment: This could work but I wanted to understand why do I get two process count, thanks!